# Rsync - how to escape special in filter

Tags: rsync

I try to delete a folder on remote host with the rsync command but the folder's name contains a brackets ("[" and "]"), a sample to try :

```
rsync -vd --delete --include=my_folder[1] --exclude=* /tmp/folder/ /your/folder/
```

i have tried --protect-args but this args work only for space character.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to escape the square brackets, eg `--include=my_folder\\[1\\]`. Note that you need to double the escape character, since the shell will interpret the first instance.

Comment: Quote or escape all wildcards on the command line, or they may get expanded before `rsync` even sees them. In this example, I'd use `... --include="my_folder[1]" --exclude="*" ...`